# confusing about android minSDK

Tags: android

I have a question about minSDK. I took a project example in here: [Contacts Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).

This project has a `minSDK = 5`. And in `styles.xml` some attribute which require higher sdk version like:

```
android:textAllCaps --> min 14
android:fontFamily --> min 16
```

But that project so no any error and run fine.

When I copy some style into my `styles.xml` in my project. It causes an error:

```
android:textAllCaps requires API level 14 (current min is 11)
...
```

Can someone help me with the compile error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use those styles in the respective minSDK version by using resource qualifiers. In your resource directory: there is base `styles`, add folders to res/`styles-v14` (for use in ice-cream sandwich and greater, where minSDK is 14) and `styles-v16` (so on so forth if you need the styles to be applied when available)

Now when the style needs a higher SDK version, place it in respective style resource directory. textAllCaps goes into styles-v14, android:fontFamily goes into styles-v16.

More can be found here on resource qualifiers ;) 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Hope this helps buddy, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: previously misunderstood the question/scenario. Sorry!

I think the problem is your Target API level. Make sure that the target api level is at least the level in which the APIs were introduced. In this case, 14.

If you build from command line you would just do

android update project -p  -t

(I think what the command does is just update project.properties and sets target=android-14)

Comment: you dont understand my question? my question is they worked fine in a sample project with minSDK=5 but not working in my project with minSDK =11

Comment: @s60 Hey yes sorry I misunderstood your question. I've updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: I always target lastest sdk, 19 i think

Comment: @s60 Do you have a <uses-sdk> tag in your AndroidManifest? It might be helpful to compare your AndroidManifest with the one of the project you took the styles from.

Comment: of course, it auto generated when create project    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: btw, in the end i removed allTextCaps and fontFamily so it's no issue